# Form field is required even if not defined so

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

I am using Net 6 with Fluent Validation and I have a form with the field:

```
  <form method="post" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create" asp-antiforgery="true" autocomplete="off">
    <label asp-for="Description">Description</label>
    <input asp-for="Description" type="text"> 
    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="error"></span>
    ...
    <button class="submit" name="button">Create</button>   
  </form>
```

The `ProductModel` is:

```
public class ProductModel {

  public String Description { get; set; }

  // ...
}
```

And the ProductModel Fluent Validator is:

public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator {

```
public ModelValidator() {

  RuleFor(x => x.Description)
    .Length(0, 200).WithMessage("Do not exceed 200 characters");

  // ...

}
```

}

When I submit the form I get an error on description if I let it empty:

```
The Description field is required.
```

But my validator is not requiring the description.

This happens to all fields. When not filled I get a similar error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did a little bit of digging, this seems to be due to a problem relating to model validation changes; specifically in ASP Net 6. I found a documentation link that can explain it better than me but I'll give a code implementation also: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcoptions-suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes)

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);

//Removes the required attribute for non-nullable reference types.
```

Hope this helps, I've taken this code straight from the MS docs, so if it doesn't fix your issue, there is likely another cause.

Comment: I think you can also use [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)] as an attribute... so right above public String Description { get; set; }

Answer (score 3):

Here is very detailed explaintion about this issue in the MC document:

> Gets or sets a value that determines if the inference of
> RequiredAttribute for properties and parameters of non-nullable
> reference types is suppressed. If false (the default), then all
> non-nullable reference types will behave as-if [Required] has been
> applied. If true, this behavior will be suppressed; nullable reference
> types and non-nullable reference types will behave the same for the
> purposes of validation.

There are two methods to solve this problem, one global and one partial.

You can set:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true)
```

In your `Program.cs` (.Net6), After using this method, all properties can be null.

Another method is in your model, you can set properties like this:

```
public class ProductModel {

  public String? Description { get; set; }

  // ...
}
```

`?` means this property can be null, in this method, You can specify which properties can be null.

Answer (score 1):

I received tons of validation errors when trying to use my asp.net API in the form of `The {fieldName} field is required`

Found out that this is due to Nullable Reference Types in C# 8

I opted out of this behavior via the `.csproj` file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```